# Is it possible to send emails automatically to users from front-end React JS?

Tags: reactjs, email

Is there a method that allows me to automatically send an emails to users when they click a button? I have the email-address and the data that needs to be sent available in the front-end of our React application.

For now in research mode...

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at EmailJS**

You have to create a service. They have an option for personal mail service as well. I am sharing two links for your reference as well.

[Link1](https://martinezjf2.medium.com/how-to-setup-emailjs-33809350f0f8) and [Link2](https://dev.to/iwaniukooo11/send-e-mails-directly-from-front-end-with-js-5d7d)

Answer (score 0):

You cant not send email directly from client side however you can try [emailjs](https://www.emailjs.com/) or [NodeMailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/). This will allow you to send mail from javascript application without any server.